# What is the correct Ivy resolver configuration to resolve Spring artifacts without using EBR?

Tags: spring, ivy

The Spring documentation states that there are four ways to get their artifacts http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#dependency-management. It also states that one should not mix repositories. It goes on to describe using Maven to get artifacts from their Maven repository (http://maven.springframework.org/release/) and Ivy to get artifacts from their EBR repository (http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/release/).

What I want is to use their Maven repository with Ivy (I've decided I don't want to use the EBR). What is the appropriate resolver configuration for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ivy is fully compatible with Maven repositories. Use the [ibiblio](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/resolver/ibiblio.html) resolver as follows:

```
<ibiblio name="spring" m2compatible="true" root="http://maven.springframework.org/release"/>
```